# How to enable dark mode in serverfault

Tags: discussion, linux

I have been using stack overflow for a few months now, and I really enjoy the dark mode feature. I recently tried to find the same feature on serverfault, but I couldn't seem to find it. Does anyone know if there is a way to enable dark mode on serverfault?

Could someone please tell me how to activate dark mode here?

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know if there is a way to enable dark mode on serverfault?

[There ain't](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/) - officially

> For now, we have no plans to bring dark mode to the many sites across the Stack Exchange network. Many of the designs on our sites have been around long enough that converting them to dark mode would require redoing the artwork completely. We would prefer to avoid giving anyone across our network a substandard experience and we don’t want to change those elements without the input of these communities.

There's [userscripts that you can use to achieve this](https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-exchange-dark-mode). YMMV.